# Citizen of an alphanumeric town

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> I can be found in an alphanumeric town,
>   Mostly above one who has a crown.
>
> If you think I'm high, I can also go down.
>   And I can be replaced, but only by a clown.
>
> You don't know it's me until I'm turned around,
>   Unless you're a deceiver and the town is a battleground.

**What am I?**

Comment: Are the occasional grammar slips deliberate, or can I fix them up to e.g. "Unless you are *a* deceiver and *the* town is *a* battleground"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing you're

> An **ace** in a deck of cards.

I can be found in an alphanumeric town,

> Specific cards in the deck are usually denoted by both letters and numbers, e.g. H for hearts, D for diamonds, etc

Mostly above one who has a crown.

> In a sorted deck, the Ace is usually 'above' the King (who wears a crown in the picture)

If you think I'm high, I can also go down.

> In blackjack, and many other games, the ace can denote a value of 1 or 11 depending on the situation

And I can be replaced, but only by a clown.

> In some card games, the Joker (aka Clown) trumps the Ace (e.g. in some Poker games, Joker can denote Any card)

You don't know it's me until I'm turned around,

> This was the giveaway, you don't know if a card is an Ace without turning it over

Unless you're a deceiver and the town is a battleground. **Edited**

> Most likely referring to **Ace in the hole**, in which on the *battleground* (e.g. game of Poker), a special weapon (i.e. our Ace) is kept hidden by the deceiver (e.g. a player) which can be used to win the round

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of:

> The Marshal in Stratego.

I can be found in an alphanumeric town,

> The pieces are identified by numbers (or a letter, in the case of bombs and the Spy.)

Mostly above one who has a crown.

> Not sure on this, but Stratego looks to be distributed in the UK and/or Australia by Crown and Andrews, whose logo is (unsurprisingly) crown-like. (It's distributed by Milton-Bradley in the US, I believe.)

If you think I'm high, I can also go down.

> The Marshal is the highest ranked piece, but it can be beaten.

And I can be replaced, but only by a clown.

> ?

You don't know it's me until I'm turned around,

> The identities of the pieces in Stratego are secret until they attack or get attacked.

Unless you're a deceiver and the town is a battleground.

> The only piece that can beat the Marshal (aside from the other Marshal, or trying to attack a Bomb) is the Spy.

Answer (score 1):

What am I?

> The queen in chess.

I can be found in an alphanumeric town,

> The squares on a chess board are often identified
> by an alphanumeric coordinate system, A1 through H8.

Mostly above one who has a crown.

> The queen is more powerful than the king.

If you think I’m high, I can also go down.

> The queen can be captured (i.e., killed) without ending the game.

And I can be replaced, but only by a clown.

> You can get a new queen by promoting a pawn,
> which, otherwise, is not always taken seriously.

You don’t know it’s me until I’m turned around,
Unless you’re a deceiver …

> ?

… and the town is a battleground.

> The meanings of the chess pieces and the rules of the games
> are significant only when you’re *playing* chess;
> i.e., having a battle on the chess board.

**What am I?**

> The queen in chess.

Comment: No, but! **maybe spoiler ahead**, You are close. Going in right direction. I think when you find an answer, you will know what each line means (well, I hope).